# Groovy as keyword

Tags: groovy

The following code returns an exception:

```
String x = "12"
double y = x
```

However this one doesn't:

```
String x = "12"
double y = x as double
```

In my application, I have a string x, and I would like to try automatically to cast it with the 'as' keyword to the class of the variable I am affecting it to, though I don't know the class of `y` in advance. Is that possible without some witchcraft, such as using `as y.class` or something?

```
String x = "12"
y = x
```

The above code returns an error if y happens not to be a string (such as a double), though I'd like it to try to cast x to the type of y before failing.

Comment: Use a conversion library (which may still throw an exception if it's inconvertible), create a factory (meh), or just catch the exception and handle it?

Answer (score 4):

The expression `x as double` is the same as the method call `x.asType(Double)`. So you can use this simple pagan spell:

```
String x = "12"
double y

y = x.asType(y.class)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can test it before casting:

```
groovy:000> s="x12"
===> x12
groovy:000> s.isNumber() ? s.toDouble() : null
===> null
groovy:000> s = "12"
===> 12
groovy:000> s.isNumber() ? s.toDouble() : null
===> 12.0
```